# notify adapter after fetch new data

Tags: android, fragment, retrofit2

I have an adapter which won't get notified after fetching new data by Retrofit however, I'm using `notifyDataSetChanged` and get success in the logs but nothing works either :(
Also I tried to use local array with this adapter and it works great.

```
public class alberrClassNews extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<alberrNewsListContent> alberrNews = new ArrayList<alberrNewsListContent>();
    private final String TAG = "Get JSONArray";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alberrnewsclass, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("nnnn");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.alberrNewsList);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        final alberrNewsAdapter aNA = new alberrNewsAdapter(getActivity(), alberrNews);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(aNA);


        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("loading");
        progressDialog.show();

        final Retrofit alberrRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://nn.com/abbn/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        alberrService service = alberrRetrofit.create(alberrService.class);


        Call<JSONArray> call = service.alberrNews();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONArray> call, Response<JSONArray> response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.i(TAG, "success");

                try{
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.body().getJSONArray(0);
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        alberrNewsListContent newsContent = new alberrNewsListContent();

                        newsContent.setAlberrNewsTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        newsContent.setAlberrNewsSubject(jsonObject.getString("subject"));
                        newsContent.setAlberrNewsImage(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                        alberrNews.add(newsContent);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                aNA.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONArray> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed");
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    "no connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Adapter Class

```
public class alberrNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<alberrNewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<alberrNewsListContent> newsListContent;
        private Context context;

        public alberrNewsAdapter(Context ncontext , List<alberrNewsListContent> nnewsListContent ){
            this.context = ncontext;
            this.newsListContent = nnewsListContent;
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.alberrnewscontent, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(alberrNewsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            final alberrNewsListContent newsContent = newsListContent.get(position);

            holder.alberrNewsTitle.setText(newsContent.getAlberrNewsTitle());
            holder.alberrNewsSubject.setText(newsContent.getAlberrNewsSubject());

            Glide.with(context)
                 .load(newsContent.getAlberrNewsImage())
                 .override(300, 260)
                 .into(holder.alberrNewsImage);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return newsListContent.size();
        }


        public void replaceDataSet(List<alberrNewsListContent> alberrNews){
            this.newsListContent = alberrNews;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView alberrNewsTitle;
            TextView alberrNewsSubject;
            ImageView alberrNewsImage;
            CardView alberrNewsCardView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                alberrNewsTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.alberrNewsTitle);
                alberrNewsSubject = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.alberrNewsSubject);
                alberrNewsImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.alberrNewsImage);
                alberrNewsCardView = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.alberrNewsCardView);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `alberrNewsAdapter`, you can create a new method called `replaceDataSet()` which will replace your dataset in the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

```
private List<alberrNewsListContent> alberrNews alberrNews;


public void replaceDataSet(List<alberrNewsListContent> alberrNews){
    this.alberrNews = alberrNews;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

And in `onResponse()` instead of calling   `aNA.notifyDataSetChanged();` call  `aNA.replaceDataSet();`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, in addition I notice in logcat JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0) , what does this mean?

Comment: Did you tried calling call  aNA.replaceDataSet(); instead of aNA.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onResponse() ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes I tried and got same result

Answer (score 0):

Pass new list content to the adapter via public method and call notifyDataSetChanged(); inside that method. Currently, you're not updating the list inside the adapter.